# ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar from a table column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a products table with product_data column  ( JSONB type ) and data is in below format.

```
 [{
    "Price": 34599,
    "Units": 1,
    "productId": 3,
    "componentId": 0,
    "isDuplicate": false,
    "productCode": "PRD-3",
    "productName": "OnePlus 6T",
    "UnitDiscount": 0,
    "discountType": "1",
    "componentCode": "",
    "componentList": [{
        "componentId": 5,
        "componentCode": "ACC-1",
        "componentName": "Charger",
        "componentActive": true,
        "componentTaxCode": null,
        "componentCategory": "General",
        "componentUnitPrice": 0,
        "componentCategoryId": 1,
        "componentReorderValue": 20
    }, {
        "componentId": 6,
        "componentCode": "ACC-2",
        "componentName": "Earphone",
        "componentActive": true,
        "componentTaxCode": null,
        "componentCategory": "General",
        "componentUnitPrice": 0,
        "componentCategoryId": 1,
        "componentReorderValue": 20
    }],
    "productUnitPrice": 34599,
    "UnitPriceDiscount": 34599,
    "componentCategory": "",
    "componentUnitPrice": ""
}, {
    "Price": 1200,
    "Units": 1,
    "productId": 3,
    "componentId": 5,
    "isDuplicate": false,
    "productCode": "PRD-3",
    "productName": "OnePlus 6T",
    "UnitDiscount": 0,
    "discountType": "1",
    "componentCode": "ACC-1",
    "componentList": [{
        "componentId": 5,
        "componentCode": "ACC-1",
        "componentName": "Charger",
        "componentActive": true,
        "componentTaxCode": null,
        "componentCategory": "General",
        "componentUnitPrice": 0,
        "componentCategoryId": 1,
        "componentReorderValue": 20
    }, {
        "componentId": 6,
        "componentCode": "ACC-2",
        "componentName": "Earphone",
        "componentActive": true,
        "componentTaxCode": null,
        "componentCategory": "General",
        "componentUnitPrice": 0,
        "componentCategoryId": 1,
        "componentReorderValue": 20
    }],
    "componentName": "Charger",
    "productUnitPrice": "",
    "UnitPriceDiscount": 1200,
    "componentCategory": "General",
    "componentUnitPrice": "1200"
}, {
    "Price": 800,
    "Units": 1,
    "productId": 3,
    "componentId": 6,
    "isDuplicate": false,
    "productCode": "PRD-3",
    "productName": "OnePlus 6T",
    "UnitDiscount": 0,
    "discountType": "1",
    "componentCode": "ACC-2",
    "componentList": [{
        "componentId": 5,
        "componentCode": "ACC-1",
        "componentName": "Charger",
        "componentActive": true,
        "componentTaxCode": null,
        "componentCategory": "General",
        "componentUnitPrice": 0,
        "componentCategoryId": 1,
        "componentReorderValue": 20
    }, {
        "componentId": 6,
        "componentCode": "ACC-2",
        "componentName": "Earphone",
        "componentActive": true,
        "componentTaxCode": null,
        "componentCategory": "General",
        "componentUnitPrice": 0,
        "componentCategoryId": 1,
        "componentReorderValue": 20
    }],
    "componentName": "Earphone",
    "productUnitPrice": "",
    "UnitPriceDiscount": 800,
    "componentCategory": "General",
    "componentUnitPrice": "800"
}]
```

When fetching data from below query it showing cannot fetch scalar elements while JSONB data is in array form when copy this data in query then its working please help.

```
  SELECT product_data from (
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(PRODUCT_DATA) as  product_data  FROM PRODUCTS 
    ) X
```

while copying this jsonb data instead of column into query then its working fine.

Comment: its typo , now corrected

Comment: I presume you should be performing some other operation with this query. A simple select query which you mentioned does work without issues. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d8d2d395c5dc5b92626837c34502092d

Comment: no simply select return error cannot extract element from scalar, its working when pasting json data instead of column name but when using column name returning error.,

Comment: I tested in versions Postgres 9.6, 10 and 11. It works for me, not sure In which tool you are receiving that error

Comment: Probably one of your table rows has a field with non-array data. Try something like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_data IS NOT NULL AND NOT product_data::TEXT LIKE '[%]'`